# Datareader.HasRow is wrong

Tags: c#, datareader

Can anyone confirm or dispute a problem I'm having accessing an ACCDB database with a `DataReader`. I setup the `DataReader` and query the database. When I check `DataReader.HasRows`, I get true, no matter if records are present or not.

I've double verified that the data table is empty, no records at all, but `DataReader.HasRows` still says it got records.

If I go on and try `DataReader.Read`, when I know there are no records returned, I get an error saying "No data exists for the row/column." which would be expected.

Has anyone seen this before? Or can you say this doesn't happen?

Thanks

```
sql = @"SELECT a.License, a.ClassID, a.CurrentlyIn, a.TotalScans " +
    @"FROM Attendance a " +
    @"WHERE a.License = " + myScan.LicenseInt +
        @" AND a.ClassID = " + myScan.ClassID + ";";
_parent.StatusOutput(sql);

cmdDB = new OleDbCommand(sql, cnDB);
try
{
    //cnDB.Open();

    drDB = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();
    if (drDB.HasRows)
    {
        _parent.StatusOutput("Data reader has no rows");
    }
    else
    {
        _parent.StatusOutput("Data reader has rows.");
        drDB.Read();
        _parent.StatusOutput(drDB["License"].ToString() + ", " + drDB["ClassID"].ToString());
    }
```

There we go. Sorry for my confusion on how to post this.

Comment: Can you include a code snippet which demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: Also include the .Net version and profile.

Comment: You could have no rows and still produce a query that will have HasRows set to true. It would depend on the query. It could be something else in your code. As @EkoostikMartin said, please post a code snippet that produces this.

Comment: I'm using VS2010. It is a forms application with .Net Framework 4 Client Profile. Below is the code and the test I'm running.

Comment: sql = @"SELECT a.License, a.ClassID, a.CurrentlyIn, a.TotalScans " +
 @"FROM Attendance a " +
 @"WHERE a.License = " + myScan.LicenseInt +
  @" AND a.ClassID = " + myScan.ClassID + ";";
_parent.StatusOutput(sql);

cmdDB = new OleDbCommand(sql, cnDB);
try
{
 //cnDB.Open();

 drDB = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();
 if (drDB.HasRows)
 {
  _parent.StatusOutput("Data reader has no rows");
 }
 else
 {
  _parent.StatusOutput("Data reader has rows.");
  drDB.Read();
  _parent.StatusOutput(drDB["License"].ToString() + ", " + drDB["ClassID"].ToString());
 }

Comment: Well that made a mess. How can I post the code as a reply. It won't seem to let me reply to my own message.

Comment: Is this really what you meant: `if (drDB.HasRows)`? Shouldn't it be `if (!drDB.HasRows)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample code as it is here If reader HAS the rows then it prints the  error

and if reader Does not have the rows it prints that it Has and reads and throws exception

swap:

```
if (drDB.HasRows)
        {
            _parent.StatusOutput("Data reader has rows.");
            drDB.Read();
            _parent.StatusOutput(drDB["License"].ToString() + ", " + drDB["ClassID"].ToString());

                   }
        else
        {
            _parent.StatusOutput("Data reader has no rows");

        }
```

Comment: When this code runs, I know that the SQL statement returns no rows, but the output statement says "Data reader has rows." That means the drDB.HasRows returns true, even though there are no row. I put the output statement in the true condition to see if it would give me some data, but it come back with no data present. Which is true because I know there are no rows returned.

Comment: Dumb, dumb, dumb mistake. Sorry for bothering you guys with it. Once again, don't code in a hurry or when your tired. Thanks!